# Automated tests in a web site

Tags: automated-tests

I was studying automated testing in Python and I was wondering if there is a way to make automated tests in a website, checking if the appearance is equal to the initial design and checking if every button/link is working as expected.

Comment: You can use [Selenium Webdriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to automate websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the popular & free test automation framework is ROBOT Framework. I can suggest you to use this framework if you are looking for a most popular free one. 
Refer to this link: http://robotframework.org

If you need to do test automation on GUI, then you need to do it with selenium. This is why ROBOT Framework is so popular because it contains many libraries and one of its powerful library is Selenium2Library. Refer below.
Refer to this link: http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html

In ROBOT Framework, there are 'built-in' and 'collections' library that you can use to perform some arithmetic, comparison operations.

There is a robotframework tag/group in this stack overflow for you to check.